# Bash: Is -e equivalent to -f || -d?

Tags: bash, shell, file, filesystems

In my projects I use the pattern

```sh
if [ -f "$path" ] || [ -d "$path" ]; then
    echo "$path exists"
fi
```

to check whether `$path` exists on the file system, regardless of whether it's a file or directory. Is this *exactly* equivalent to just doing

```sh
if [ -e "$path" ]; then
    echo "$path exists"
fi
```

? What about for special files such as symbolic links or devices? Are there any platform dependent details to be aware of? I use Bash, but I would like to know about subtle differences between shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. `-e pathname` only tests if `pathname` resolves to an existing directory entry. `-f` and `-d`, on the other hand, also tests if the entry is for a regular file and a directory, respectively.

For example, if `pathname` resolves to a FIFO (or a block special file, or a character device, or a socket, etc.), `[ -e pathname ]` returns true; but `[ -f pathname ] || [ -d pathname ]` returns false.

As for symbolic links, neither `-e`, `-f`, nor `-d` differentiates them from entries they resolve to. If `pathname` names a regular file, a directory, or a symbolic link to a regular file or a directory, both `[ -e pathname ]` and `[ -f pathname ] || [ -d pathname ]` return true. And if `pathname` names a symbolic link to an entry that doesn't exist (i.e. a broken symbolic link), both return false.

Comment: And POSIX specifies test operators `-b`, `-c`, `-p`, and `-S` for block special files, character special files, FIFOs (named **p**ipes), and sockets, respectively, so it is not specific to Bash that `-f` and `d` fail to cover all the possibilities.  Also, symbolic links are normally followed, but *broken* symbolic links are not -- they will be matched only by `-e`, `-h`, or `-L`.

Comment: @John No, -e won't match them. Only -[hL]

Comment: I stand corrected, at least inasmuch as testing with Bash is concerned.  However, POSIX's wording could be read to specify that `-e` would indeed evaluate to true for broken symlinks, so if one is trying to write portable shell scripts then it might be best not to make any assumptions here.

Comment: Did you mistype?  That `-e broken_link` would evaluate to true is what I said, that I thought you contradicted, and that I confirmed in fact was not the case for Bash (v4.3).

Comment: In any case, compare to the spec for `-h`, which uses almost the same wording as that for `-e`: *True if pathname resolves to an existing directory entry for a symbolic link. False if pathname cannot be resolved, or [...]*. If we accept, as seems natural, that "an existing directory entry for a symbolic link" is a specific case of "an existing directory entry", then it would follow that if `-h` evaluates to true for `broken_link` then `-e` should evaluate to true for it too. But Bash exhibits different behavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I meant to say *`-e broken_link` evaluates to false*, because `broken_link` resolves to an entry that doesn't exist. The spec. for the `-h` primary also says *If the final component of pathname is a symbolic link, that symbolic link is not followed*. In `-h /path/to/broken_link`, `broken_link` is the final component, and that it would resolve to an entry that doesn't exist does not matter, because it is a symbolic link and thus, not followed. In the case of `-e /path/to/broken_link` though, it does, as the final component, which is a symbolic link, is followed.

Comment: And bash is not the only shell that behaves that way. All Almquist and Korn Shell derivatives on my computer exhibits the same behavior.